# posting items from asp.net website to craigslist

Tags: asp.net, api, posting, craigslist

here an example of posting to craigslist . http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface in perl language.

any craigslist posting example in asp.net ?

I converted the perl example (from above link ) into asp.net but still generates an error , error is " The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine "
anyone have an idea about this. thanks in advance
here is my code ,

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0'?><rdf:RDF xmlns='http://purl.org/rss/1.0/'  xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#' xmlns:cl='http://www.craigslist.org/about/cl-bulk-ns/1.0'> <channel><items><rdf:li rdf:resource='NYCBrokerHousingSample1'/><rdf:li rdf:resource='NYCBrokerHousingSample2'/> </items> <cl:auth username='fawad_ashfaq@hotmail.com' password='*******' accountID='14'/>  </channel> <item rdf:about='NYCBrokerHousingSample1'> <cl:category>fee</cl:category>     <cl:area>nyc</cl:area>  <cl:subarea>mnh</cl:subarea> <cl:neighborhood>Upper West Side</cl:neighborhood> <cl:housingInfo price='1450' bedrooms='0'                     sqft='600'/> <cl:replyEmail  privacy='C'>bulkuser@bulkposterz.net</cl:replyEmail> <cl:brokerInfo companyName='Joe Sample and Associates' feeDisclosure='fee disclosure here' /> <title>Spacious Sunny Studio in Upper West  Side</title> <description><![CDATA[  posting body here ]]></description> </item> </rdf:RDF>";    



    string BASE_URL = "https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/post";
      HttpPost(BASE_URL, xml ); Private static string HttpPost(string url, string postData)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
    using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
        writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    string result = string.Empty;

    request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader readStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
    }
    return result;

} // end HttpPost
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Fiddle2(windows) or Charles(os x) to capture http request and response, compare the difference between the perl example and asp.net example, then you may find the 'bug'.

Comment: I used the Fiddle2 and debugging but thats generates  BAD RESPONSE

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by adding

```
request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
```